Creating a random permutation or random walk with a constraint
Two ways of looking at the same problem. One is a permutation of a set of N 1s and N -1s such that apart from the final sum of zero, all partial sums from the start are positive. The other is a simple one dimensional random walk +1 or -1 that finishes at the start, only ever having been one side of it. The problem is to create, equiprobably, one such permutation/walk, assuming that you have access to whatever random numbers you need. The number of such results is given by a Catalan number. And the approach of generate an example, check, if not suitable discard and repeat, is unsuitable as the mean number of attempts needed per result goes up significantly with N. (A bounded mean number of attempts with a small bound would be acceptable, in general I don't need a fixed randomness process, although that would be better.)
[I'm actually interested in the case of N ones and N-1 -1s, with all positive partial sums. One application is 1 means push something on stack, -1 means combine two popped items from stack and push result back onto stack, and all possible patterns of that. You can add a final -1 for pop final result off stack to make the more symmetric problem posed above.]

So, random permutations of a 50/50 mixture of +1, -1? Just keep swapping randomly selected pairs.

I don't think that works. It has the same problem as new permutations each time, the number of swaps increases with N. But I think there's a bigger problem. We need to start with a random permutation, anything else would introduce an obvious bias. Except we know the first two values are 1 and the last two are -1, so fix those. So I ran some Monte Carlo results (ten million each) initially to see how the number of swaps increased. But then to check for an even distribution of final permutations. Monte Carlo only gives us an indication, but it's an all but certain not indication (I tried N = 6.)

I see, so you are actually looking for first passage paths of length $n$. I think that by identifying the regions between consecutive zero crossings and flipping the negative ones, will solve the issue a'la the reflection method.

No, I don't think so, because I want no returns to zero, not just no negative values. And even if not, I don't think this solves the uniformity problem.

I can generate your list of $n$ $(+1)$'s and $n$ $(-1)$'s using at most $2n$ random numbers between $0$ and $1$ and $O(n)$ computation time, without any rejection sampling. More generally, given positive integers $p$ and $q$, with $p\ge q$, I will show to randomly arrange $p$ copies of $+1$ and $q$ copies of $-1$, subject to the constraint that all partial sums are positive.
First, a simpler question. When choosing a random array of $p$ copies of $+1$ and $q$ copies of $-1$ with positive partial sums, what is the probability the last item is $+1$? The probability is equal to the number of such arrangements whose last item is $+1$, divided by the total number of arrangements. Furthermore, the number of arrangements whose last item is $+1$ is equal to the number of arrangements of $(p-1)$ copies of $+1$ and $q$ copies of $-1$ with positive partial sums.
Now, consider the related counting problem; how many valid sequences of $p$ $1$'s and $q$ $(-1)$'s are there? This is exactly answered by Bertrand's ballot theorem. Letting $N(p,q)$ be the number of such sequences, Bertrand proved that
$$
p>q\quad\implies\quad N(p,q)=\frac{p-q}{p+q}\binom{p+q}{p}.
$$
Putting all of this together, you should be able to see that the following pseudocode correctly generates these lists uniformly at random. I implemented this algorithm in Python as a sanity check: Try it online!.
Input:    Nonnegative integers $p$ and $q$, with $p\ge q$.
Output: A list $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{p+q}$, where $p$ entries are $+1$ and $q$ entries are $-1$, and all partial sums (except the entire sum) are positive. The output is random, such that all possible lists are equally likely.

If $q=0$, output the list where all entries equal to $+1$.
Otherwise, assume  $q\ge 1$.

First, set $x_{p+q}$ as follows:

If $p=q$, set $x_{p+q}=-1$.

If $p>q$, then randomly set $x_{p+q}=1$ or $x_{p+q}=-1$, in such a way that $$\mathbb P(x_{p+q}=1)=\frac{N(p-1,q)}{N(p,q)},\qquad 
\mathbb P(x_{p+q}=-1)=\frac{N(p,q-1)}{N(p,q)}.$$ For example, you could let $u$ be a uniform random number in the range $(0,1)$, then set $x_{p+q}=1$ if $u\le \frac{N(p-1,q)}{N(p,q)}$, and set $x_{p+q}=-1$ otherwise.



Finally, determine the rest of the list $x_1,\dots,x_{p+q-1}$. Let $p'$ be the number of $(+1)'s$ in the remaining list, and let $q'$ be the number of $(-1)$'s remaining. That is,
$$
p'=\begin{cases}p-1 & \text{if } x_{p+q}=+1 \\ p & \text{if }x_{p+q}=-1\end{cases}\qquad
q'=\begin{cases}q & \text{if } x_{p+q}=+1 \\ q-1 & \text{if }x_{p+q}=-1\end{cases}.$$Then, determine $x_1,\dots,x_{p+q-1}$ via a recursive call to this method with inputs $p'$ and $q'$.



This looks like it's exactly what I want, but I need to read up on Bertrand's ballot problem and to implement it to confirm that.

I edited to include my Python implementation, along with tests which show that the generation appears to be uniform. Also, I included the Wikipedia page for Betrand's ballot theorem as a source.

Just to confirm, Mike's solution - and equally valuably the name of the problem - was exactly what I needed. I used the pseudo-code rather than the Python. (I implemented in C++.)

Happy to help! Could I ask you to click the green check mark next to my answer? This is how you accept an answer.
